# Finding a check made out to "Cash"

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, money, lost-and-found

Is it permissible to cash a check that is found in the street, if the check is made out to "cash" and after attempting to locate an owner, none is found.

Would it be considered the same as finding a $20 bill in the street?

**Additional details for the question**

if a significant amount of time passes (say 1 month) would it be more permissible to cash a found check. This is considering that the writer of the check and the original intended receiver of the check would have had ample time to cancel the check, if they did not, what could that mean in our case?

(Additionally, is it legal to cash a found check? And would that affect the halacha of this situation?)

Comment: The maker of the check is usually written on it.

Comment: Regardless you can find out who the owner is with the account number on the check so it has a siman

Comment: What if the person who finds it is unable to contact the name on the check, or if the name is a general name like "john smith"?

Comment: You can contact the bank

Comment: Actually, this is a case when you can do hashavas aveidah without knowing who the owner is.  If you rip up the check the owner keeps the money.

Comment: Unless it's a cashier's check

Comment: @Heshy in an important technical way yes, but in a practical way, we aren't sure if it's a check that's already been handed over to someone who needs to bank/cash it. They won't be able to if it's not returned to them. If the writer of the check can be identified from the account number, then it's possible to get it back to its owner. If not, then what makes this different from any other non-identifiable lost item? I think we can say that the writer of the check didn't lose their money (just a promissory note), yet, so cashing the check is literally stealing?

Comment: The more I think about it the more I find this a very interesting question

Comment: @RabbiKaii not necessarily. Once the person realizes he lost it, he would ask the maker to stop the check. If it still wasn’t cashed, that can be done and a new one can be given. So the loser, is not meyaesh like they are by money

Comment: @RabbiKaii i added some additional aspects to the question. I too am intrigued on what the practical applications would be.

Comment: Money cannot have a siman, as it is designed to be passed around and change hands. A check made out to cash would presumably be the same, and have the status of cash.

Answer (score 2):

no. The reason is for a few reasons:

1. Because the check is unique, it is identifiable and the owener will not have ye-ush.
2. Finding the check is not the same as finding the money. While the bearer of the check may have given up on finding the money, we are not clear on what arrangement the payer had with the payee. Using the check may end up hurting the payer, who may have issued a new check to the payee. This argument might not be valid at all, and essentially boils down to whether a person has a mitzva of hashavat aveda for a sh'tar.